Reparametrization trick in GMM
Assume I have two random variables, $X$ and $Y$. If $p(Y|X)=\mathcal{N}(Y;\alpha.X,\sigma^2\mathbb{I})$, I can calculate $Y$ by using reparametrization trick:
$Y=\alpha.X+\sigma.\epsilon$, with $\epsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$
So, how can I apply the reparametrization trick to calculate $Y$ when the distribution changes from a Gaussian to a GMM? I.e. $p(Y|X)=\sum^K_{k=1}\pi_k\mathcal{N}(\mu_k,\sigma_k^2\mathbb{I})$
Thank you
